# How to display selected rows with a multiselect jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a multiselect jqgrid and I would like to get the selected rows and display them in an other page.

I tried with an ajax call but I can't figure out how to display my data, I'm kinda lost and I don't really know how to proceed...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`getGridParam`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method along with the [`selarrrow`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option to get the ID's of all the selected rows. For example:

```
var selectedIDs = jQuery('#mygrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

*Aside: Note this will only retrieve the selected rows on the current page. If you have selected rows across multiple pages, you will need to add additional application logic to keep track of the ID's.*

You can then use this information to retrieve the data for these ID's and display everything you need in another page.

Does that help?

Comment: Well actually, I already use var ids = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'); to get my ids, then I tried to use an ajax call to display them in my other page but I can't figure out how to do it... Can I do it without ajax ?

Comment: Where is your "other page"? Are you trying to select the rows in another browser window? A page in another frame? Another page in the same session???

Comment: I'm using jqgrid in my main page, and I want to display informations on my selected rows in a new tab.
I think I found a way to do it... I wrap my jqgrid with a form with a target="_blank" but I don't know how to give my checkboxes a name yet...

Comment: I managed to add a name in the multiselect checkbox using jquery.
`$('#ConsultationImprimePlanningForm').submit(function(){
    var grid = jQuery('#jqList');
    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');

    for (x in ids) {
        $('#jqg_jqList_'+ids[x]).attr('name', ids[x]);
    }
    
    return true;
});`

it wasn't really hard though...
so with a <form> wrapping my jqgrid, a target _blank attribute and my jquery function, I have what I was looking for... maybe there's an easiest way... but this works for me.
Thanks for your time Justin

Comment: I just discovered this would return empty if you have a return false in beforeSelectRow function. Is there any other way besides css selectors to get the checked rows?